# Why Can't Suspensions be Discussed on the Meta?

Tags: discussion, moderation, suspensions

I think the reason behind any act of moderation comes under the domain of the meta discussion of the website. Thus, the reasons behind the suspensions should also be open to discussion on the meta website. I, by no means, intend to say that the decisions regarding the suspensions should be made directly based on such discussions or by popular vote. That right is rightly reserved by the expert moderators for the good. But since the suspensions are decided based on the public behavior of the user and the policy of the SE is also public, I see no harm in discussing the precise reasons behind a particular suspension. And besides, dogmatically not disclosing the information about any suspension (for example, Ron Maimon's to be explicit) seems quite silly if not anti-democratic. I know that the information can be accessed by personally emailing the moderators but I don't see why discussing it on the meta website is not encouraged.

Comment: Related: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4241/2451 , https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9650/2451

Comment: "suspensions are decided based on the public behavior of the user" ─ this is in general not true, since crucial parts of the relevant behaviour are often deleted at the time of the suspension.

Comment: And as for Ron Maimon's suspension, it's easy: it's a network-wide ban imposed by SE community managers for behaviour on other SE sites at a period (near the end of a one-year PSE-specific ban that would have expired on 2016-08-28) during which he was absent from this site. If you want to discuss Ron Maimon's current suspension, this meta is not the place  ─ take it up with SE.

Comment: Or go to Ron himself and ask him why he was banned (though be warned, his opinion/interpretation of events may differ from what SE & mods might say).

Comment: I'm not sure why this has reopen votes.  The OP flagged it as a dupe himself.